# Laravel: allow download only for logged user through api (REST)

Tags: laravel, rest, file, authentication, laravel-5

For my app, users are able to login through api authentication (`'middleware' => ['auth:api']` in `api.php`), and there are images that wish to show for logged user.

However, when I use `'middleware' => ['auth:api']` in `web.php`, user are identified not logged.

How can I protect the image and show to users that logged through ajax call? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Config the apache to forbid derectly access.

```
Alias /filepath "/data/filepath"
<Directory /data/filepath>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Check the user before write the file.

```
$local_file = 'local file path';
$download_file = 'download file name';
$download_rate = 20.5;
if($isAuthorized)
{
    if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file)) {
        header('Cache-control: private');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
        header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);
        flush();
        $file = fopen($local_file, "r");
        while (!feof($file)) {
            print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
            flush();
            ob_flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```